# Sub-menu link closes menu instead of going to specified link

Tags: jquery, menu

I'm using the code below to toggle an accordion menu, but each time an item in the child menu is clicked, the menu slides up without going to the actual link.

http://jsfiddle.net/Y2vM3/

When clicking MISC in the jsfiddle above, the menu opens. But when clicking the child link, it closes right back up. It works fine when "return false;" is removed (it's there to prevent the browser from jumping to the top of the page), but with it, the sub-menu just slides up..?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    jQuery('.menu ul').slideUp(0);

    jQuery('.menu li.sub').click(function () {
        var target = jQuery(this).children('a');
        if(target.hasClass('menu-expanded')){
            target.removeClass('menu-expanded');
        }else{
            jQuery('.menu-item > a').removeClass('menu-expanded');
            target.addClass('menu-expanded');
        }
        jQuery(this).find('ul:first')
            .slideToggle(350)
            .end()
            .siblings('li')
            .find('ul')
            .slideUp(350);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: can you add the markup?

Comment: for full client-side things please always provide a jsfiddle

Comment: @Nitzan Volman: Added

Comment: @Thomas David Plat: http://jsfiddle.net/Y2vM3/

Comment: I don't understand. You sound like the patient who tells his doctor, "It hurts when I do this." So don't do that.

Comment: after `.slideUp(350)` add `.preventdefault()` and remove `return false`

Comment: @isherwood: :) The reason I want to use "return false" is so the page wouldn't jump to the top of the page when "MISC" is clicked.

Comment: Ah. You might add that to your question.

Comment: @Davor Mlinaric: No dice, now the sub menu is open on page load and won't open/close at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `return false;` you're telling the browser to not follow the link. Use `preventDefault` instead. [Here's more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false) on the distinction.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/Y2vM3/4/

```
...
        jQuery(this).find('ul:first')
            .slideToggle(350)
            .end()
            .siblings('li')
            .find('ul')
            .slideUp(350);
        preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Also, use

```
href="javascript:void(0)"
```

instead of a hash.

Comment: When "MISC" is clicked, the browser now jumps to the top of the page :(

Comment: I'm  using WP so using "javascript:void(0)" as link won't stick, but leaving the link empty does. Cheers!